# How does raw result format returned from Microsoft SQL Server looks like?

Tags: sql-server

I have been using SQL for like 10 years but now I realised I never knew how the client actually receive and process data it gets from the server.

My question is, how does the result from Microsoft SQL Server actually look like in raw format? The same as that result from HTTP server contains HTTP headers and a `Content-Type` header to tell what the body format is (mostly HTML for web pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol name is TDS (Tabular Data Stream).

Some documentation is available at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx).
There is a very basic example of data being transferred for simple query `select 'foo' as 'bar'`

[Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304416.aspx)

```
Packet header (type, legth, etc)

01 01 00 5C 00 00 01 00 

Packet data

16 00 00 00 - headers total length
12 00 00 00 - first header length
02 00 - type
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 - data

0A 00 73 00 65 00 6C 00 65 00 63 00 74 00 20 00 
27 00 66 00 6F 00 6F 00 27 00 20 00 61 00 73 00 
20 00 27 00 62 00 61 00 72 00 27 00 0A 00 20 00 
20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 - sql
```

[Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd341261.aspx)

```
Packet header (type, legth, etc)

04 01 00 33 00 00 01 00 

Packet data

 columns metadata
81 - record id
01 - count
 first column
00 00 00 00 00 - user type
20 00 - flags
A7 - type
03 00 - length
09 04 D0 00 34 - colation
03 - column name length
62 00 61 00 72 00 - column name bytes

 rows
D1 - record id
03 00 - length
66 6F 6F - value

 ending data
FD - record id
10 00 - status
C1 00 
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - rows total
```

We can also look at parser implementation thanks to [reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs).